# Hatching in Matplotlib: Weird behaviour with eps

Tags: matplotlib, pdflatex, eps

I am producing plots in matplotlib that have hatched patches. The images are supposed to be saved as .eps for a certain journal-submission. I had to update matplotlib to 2.0.2 to get the hatching to show up in a figure saved as .eps. 
Ironically, the figures are converted to pdf during the compilation process with pdflatex. During this conversion the hatching is lost again. Here is some code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('ps')
import pylab
import numpy as np

ax = pylab.subplot(111)
data = pylab.randn(10,10)
data[:3,:3] = pylab.nan
ax.patch.set(hatch='////', edgecolor='0.8')    
data = np.ma.masked_invalid(data)
pcol = ax.pcolor(data) 

pylab.savefig('fig.eps')
```

I played with different backends. With all of them, if you now convert the eps to pdf with `epstopdf fig.eps`, the hatching disappears in the resulting pdf. The only workaround I have found is to save the figure as a pdf and then open it in inkskape and export it as an eps. Then it works fine. But shouldn't matplotlib be capable of producing the eps directly? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like the hatching done in matplotlib is using some feature that epstopdf does not support. This is not exactly a matplotlib issue per se.